# How to define a custom `textwidth` for BASH in VIM editing mode

Tags: bash, vi

The setting in my `.vimrc` is

```
set textwidth=79
```

however, this affects the BASH-prompt as well, since I'm using the vi editing mode.

Is there a way to set it for bash independently?

If not, is there an option to show somehow a ruler on the right side at the 79th column?

Comment: I'm confused. I don't think `bash` (via `readline`) uses your `.vimrc` file in any way for `vi` mode.

Comment: Sure it does ;-) I was confused too and everytime I typed in more than 79 chars in the prompt, the line wrapped and glitched… However, with Ansgars solution it's now fixed and not wrapping at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `textwidth` only for files should do what you want. Change the line

```
set textwidth=79
```

into this:

```
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd FileType * set textwidth=79
endif
```